# Django shopping cart, and testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, django

For an e-commerce web application I have written a shopping cart, and some tests for it.

I have used a course on Lynda.com, on building an e-commerce website, as inspiration on how to build the shopping cart. So it shares a lot of code with the one being thought there.

The shopping cart is obviously not finished, but I want to start testing as much of it's functionality as possible while in the process of developing it.

So, I am curious how more experienced programmers judge this piece of code.

**Shopping cart code**

```
from django.conf import settings

from plant_data.models import Product


    def __init__(self, session):
        """
        Initialize shopping cart.
        """
        self.session = session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart
    
    def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
        """
        Add new product to cart, or update quantity of item already in cart.
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                     'price': str(product.price),
                                     'name': product.name,
                                     }
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()
    
    def get_cart_list(self):
        """
        Returns the cart as a list, this format is more suitable than a dictionary for
        the frontend to make a detail view with.
        """
        cart_list = []
        print(self.cart)
        for product_id, value in self.cart.items():
            cart_list.append({
                "id": product_id,
                "name": value['name'],
                "price": value['price'],
                "quantity": value['quantity'],
            })
        return cart_list
    
    def save(self):
        self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
        self.session.modified = True
```

**The tests**

```
from decimal import Decimal

from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory

from .cart import Cart
from plant_data.models import Product


class CartInitializeTestCase(TestCase):
    # Test cart initialization
    # Possible outcomes:
    # - cart.cart is an empty dictionary (with input: session that contains no cart)
    # - cart.cart contains is equal to the cart in the session

    def setUp(self):
        self.request = RequestFactory().get('/')

        # adding session
        middleware = SessionMiddleware()
        middleware.process_request(self.request)
        self.request.session.save()

    def test_initialize_cart_clean_session(self):
        """
        The cart is initialized with a session that contains no cart.
        In the end it should have a variable cart which is an empty dict.
        """
        request = self.request
        cart = Cart(request.session)
        self.assertEqual(cart.cart, {})

    def test_initialize_cart_filled_session(self):
        """
        The cart is initialized with a session that contains a cart.
        In the end it should have a variable cart which equal to the cart that
        is in the initial session.
        """
        existing_cart = {
            '1': {
                'name': 'first name',
                'price': '1.01',
                  },
            '2': {
                'name': 'second name',
                'price': '34.1',
            }
        }
        request = self.request
        request.session['cart'] = existing_cart
        cart = Cart(request.session)
        self.assertEqual(cart.cart, existing_cart)


class CartAddTestCase(TestCase):
    # Test the add function
    # Possible outcomes:

    # Add to existing product:
    # - Add to an existing quantity
    # - Update an existing quantity

    # Add non existing product
    # - Add non existing product

    def setUp(self):
        self.request = RequestFactory().get('/')

        # adding session
        middleware = SessionMiddleware()
        middleware.process_request(self.request)
        self.request.session['cart'] = {
            '1': {
                'name': 'some name',
                'price': '1.01',
                'quantity': 8,
            },
        }
        self.request.session.save()

        self.existing_product = Product(
            id=1,
            name='some name',
            price=Decimal('1.01'),
            stock=8,
        )

        self.new_product = Product(
            id=2,
            name='other name',
            price=Decimal('2.23'),
            stock=12,
        )

    def test_cart_add_to_existing_quantity(self):
        """
        Test adding a quantity to an existing quantity.
        """
        cart = Cart(self.request.session)
        cart.add(product=self.existing_product,
                 quantity=4,
                 update_quantity=False,
                 )
        new_cart = {
            '1': {
                'name': 'some name',
                'price': '1.01',
                'quantity': 12,
            },
        }
        self.assertEqual(cart.cart, new_cart)

    def test_cart_add_update_existing_quantity(self):
        """
        Test updating existing item quantity.
        """
        cart = Cart(self.request.session)
        cart.add(product=self.existing_product,
                 quantity=4,
                 update_quantity=True,
                 )
        new_cart = {
            '1': {
                'name': 'some name',
                'price': '1.01',
                'quantity': 4,
            },
        }
        self.assertEqual(cart.cart, new_cart)

    def test_cart_add_new_product(self):
        cart = Cart(self.request.session)
        cart.add(product=self.new_product,
                 quantity=4,
                 update_quantity=False,
                 )
        new_cart = {
            '1': {
                'name': 'some name',
                'price': '1.01',
                'quantity': 8,
            },
            '2': {
                'name': 'other name',
                'price': '2.23',
                'quantity': 4,
            }
        }
        self.assertEqual(cart.cart, new_cart)


class CartGetCartListTestCase(TestCase):
    # Test get_cart_list function

    # Possible outcome:
    # - returns a list of the cart that has been put in

    def test_get_cart_list(self):
        request = RequestFactory().get('/')

        # adding session
        middleware = SessionMiddleware()
        middleware.process_request(request)
        request.session['cart'] = {
            '1': {
                'name': 'some name',
                'price': '1.01',
                'quantity': 8,
            },
            '2': {
                'name': 'other name',
                'price': '2.23',
                'quantity': 4,
            }
        }
        request.session.save()
        test_cart_list = [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "some name",
                "price": "1.01",
                "quantity": 8,
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "other name",
                "price": "2.23",
                "quantity": 4,
            },
        ]

        cart = Cart(request.session)
        cart_list = cart.get_cart_list()
        self.assertEqual(cart_list, test_cart_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

The unit tests look good. Good job!

---

```
def __init__(self, session):
    """
    Initialize shopping cart.
    """
    self.session = session
    cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    if not cart:
        cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
    self.cart = cart
```

N.B. You are missing the class signature

```
class Cart:
```

Assuming the session is a dict like object, `.get` will implement a `default` keyword argument, which will simplify this code.

```
def __init__(self, session):
    """
    Initialize shopping cart.
    """
    self.session = session
    self.cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID, {})
```

---

```
def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
    """
    Add new product to cart, or update quantity of item already in cart.
    """
    product_id = str(product.id)
    if product_id not in self.cart:
        self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                 'price': str(product.price),
                                 'name': product.name,
                                 }
    if update_quantity:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
    else:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
    self.save()
```

Storing the product price as a string (`'price': str(product.price)`) can behave weirdly you are converting from floating point numbers. Using decimal does make sense here, but may be overkill if you will only ever need 2 places of precision. It might be easier to work in cents/pennies.

I would move creating a new dictionary representation of a product. It may have non-trivial business logic in the future, and you may want to move it somewhere else. Both of these tasks will be easier when all the logic is encapsulated into a small function.

I think `update_quantity` would be better named as `set_quantity`. Update implies the new value depends on the previous value, whereas that is not the case here. If anything, I would have expected the statements inside `if update_quantity: else:` to be the other way around.

```
def product_dict(product):
    """"""
    return {
        'quantity': 0,
        'price': str(product.price),
        'name': product.name,
    }

def add(self, product, quantity=1, set_quantity=False):
    """
    Add a new product to cart, or set the quantity of item already in cart.
    """
    product_id = str(product.id)
    if product_id not in self.cart:
        self.cart[product_id] = product_dict(product)
    if set_quantity:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
    else:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
    self.save()
```